# MySQL/PHP | Is a 26 character string ( letters and dashes ) too long for indexed columns?

Tags: php, mysql, database, indexing, where-clause

I'd like to set out my websites url path like so:

`http://example.com/categories/a-specific-theme-or-subject/1`

And use PHP to select all pages like this:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE category = 'a-specific-theme-or-subject'`

But I was wondering, is this good practice, or does this have a negative effect on the speed at which the data is pulled from the database - In comparison to using a simpler single word:

`http://example.com/categories/subject/1`

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE category = 'subject'`

A `VARCHAR` column is allowed 255 characters, but I would assume that the lower the number actually used is better, but how many is too many?

I would use no more than 26 characters for any complete category name (`a-specific-theme-or-subject`).

Comment: Indexes use b-trees, they're pretty efficient for this. 26 characters is fine.

Comment: Just had a look at B-Trees and, I'm not going to pretend I understand what they are or do, but thanks - It's worth looking into further. Good to know 26 is an accepable number.

Comment: Don't worry about microoptimization like this unless you actually run into performance problems.

Comment: True, but still, prevention is better than the cure - As they say.

Comment: @wsix (love of) 'premature optimisation is the root of all evil'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:  Don't worry.

Long answer:

The hard limit on how long an indexed column can be is 191 or 255 or 767 or 3072 bytes or some intermediate values, depending on MySQL version and `CHARACTER SET`.

The practical limit on how long is, again, "don't worry".

Indexing shorter column is *slightly* better than a long column, *but* the overhead of switching to a longer column is probably worse than simply using what your application needs.

A `category VARCHAR(26)` is fine; don't worry.  And you could make that ascii or latin1 or utf8 or utf8mb4.  (The 26 *characters* would have a max of 26, 26, 78, 104 _bytes, respectively.)

The most important thing in designing a good index is tailoring it to the query.  `WHERE category = 'subject'` calls for exactly `INDEX(category)`.